# Is there a webserver for Windows Mobile 6 that can dynamically generate pages and store data?

Tags: web-server, windows-mobile

I use tiddlywiki alot, and it'd be really, really cool if I could save changes to a tiddlywiki in some mobile browser.

But it seems that with all the mobile browsers that I've tried, changes I make to my tiddlywiki cannot be saved to an SD Card.

However it seems that although some mobile browsers are quite capable of loading and saving changes that are hosted on a webserver (I've actually tried this on my blog on Tiddlyspot.com with opera-mini and successfully saved the changes.)

Now, if I could just host a webserver that runs on my Windows Mobile device, and that webserver could be capable of running a simple dynamic page generation language and some-how writing and reading from a txt file or database of some sort, I could access/modifiy my tiddlywiki's without having to pay to host them somewhere (even if I have to write the backend myself it'd be worth it!)

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a freeware webserver.](http://windows-mobile-6.handster.com/software.php?id=2891&for=Windows+Mobile+6)
[Here is another webserver.](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/Coffeehouse/246234-A-web-server-for-the-mobile-phone/#251599)

Answer (score 0):

You ***might*** be able to port cassini - http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived/cassini/